# Launch installed third-party android app via web link/html/web app?

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, deeplink

I'm making a mobile webpage that needs to have a bunch of links to various installed apps through the MDM. This is for managed devices and will launch both enterprise-internal apps and third-party. It does not need to do anything other than just launch.

I've been looking everywhere on how to make some simple basic links to simply launch the apps and nothing more.

I've tried some of the syntax below but it fails to actually open the installed app and instead just takes you to app store:

```
 <a href="intent://launch/#Intent;package=com.a14integrated.full;end"> Take a QR code </a>

<intent android:action="launch" >
     <extra android:name="com.a14integrated.full" android:value="com.a14integrated.full" />
LAUNCH?
</intent>
```

**UPDATE #1:**

After more research I'm giving this up as it doesn't seem generically possible but rather something each app maker must implement themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not generically possible -- ended up requesting intents documentation from third-party apps and implementing our own intents strategy for deep-linking into the existing apps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2(as far as I know) possible ways to achieve this

**Note** - You would need access to the source code of the app you're trying to open for both the implementations

**1.** Integrate Deep links in the App to open the app if app is installed or visited the website otherwise.

**2.** Use firebase, add the app to the firebase and implement dynamic links.